# Excesive permission level in release management for contributors group in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management

It seems that the default permission mapping on TFS Release Management (TFS 2017) for Contributors group allows to do much more things than a simple "contributor" should be allowed to do:
[image]
Of course permissions can be changed (depending of the number of TP´s this can take a while) but I don´t understand why the default mapping gives so many power. As far as I understand, Contributors group is intended to put developers. Why should a developer has permissions to change/delete a release environment, manage the release aprovers or even modify a release definition? (which probably has been properly configured by a release administrator).

Am I missunderstanding anything?

Curiously,the team build permissions for contributors are much more restricted...

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Excesive permission level in release management for contributors group in TFS

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed** and is not a issue. According to the document [Pipeline permissions and security roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#default-permissions-assigned-to-built-in-security-groups), we could to know:

> Once you have been added as a team member, you are a member of the
>   Contributors group. This allows you to define and manage builds and
>   releases. The most common built-in groups include Readers,
>   Contributors, and Project Administrators. These groups are assigned
>   the default permissions as listed below.

[image]

As we can see that the different default permissions between build and release is the option to build default permissions will have one more task **Manage build queues and build qualities** (Others are not show in the list of **ACCESS CONTROL SUMMARY**).

So, when we got to the default permission mapping on TFS Build Management, we can see following settings:

[image]

**Although** the other options except the red box are set to not set, they allow membership in the group with the permission set to take precedence. If you check those options one by one, you will find all those permission are set as **[Allow (inherited)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops#permission-settings)**, check the image from Azure Devops:

[image]

**So**, the team build permissions for contributors are not restricted than TFS Build Management.

Besides, if you feel the default mapping of contributors gives so many power, you can add a custom group and set the permissions for this group, then add those contributors to this group.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was aware of this behavior is by design, question was basically to determine if I´m putting the wrong people in contributors group according the MS best practices, because it´s not easy to explain to management why developers can modify deployment procedures stablished by release managers (sorry for spliting my comment in two pieces, I consumed the max time for editing the first one)

Comment: @Josto, Yeah, I could fully understand your pain. The root of pain lies in the difference in understanding of the permissions of contributors. MS defined the  contributors who allows you to define and manage builds and releases. But this may have too many permissions for your contributors. That is the reason why MS provide the ACCESS CONTROL SUMMARY for you, so that we could custom the permissions of contributors. If not, we will have a lot of Azure Devops Groups for different permissions request.

Comment: it would be a nice idea to have a built in group intended only to developers (i.e people who only have to push code, update workitems and nothing else). Yes, you can create the group by yourself, but you have to worry about give all required permissions and this can take a while for many TP. Anyway, I think I will create a scrip for updating contributors permissions in every TP. Thanks again for your answers :)